# Rewrite Problem - L(ast) not being respected?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm working on a CSS/JS compressing system for a site, that has basically the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

...

RewriteRule ^css/images/(.*)$ images/site/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^css/([0-9a-fA-F]{32})$ assets.php?hash=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

php_flag register_globals off
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag register_long_arrays off

# 404 Handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Right now assets.php isn't receiving the hash call, but rather index.php - if I remove the line `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

it works fine but I don't know why - shouldn't the [L] flag on the assets rewrite `RewriteRule ^css/([0-9a-fA-F]{32})$ assets.php?hash=$1 [L]` prevent any further rewrites from being executed?  I'm confused by whats happening here.

Any light you could shed on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `L` flag says "do not execute any more rules in the ruleset," which oddly enough does not imply that no more rules will be executed by `mod_rewrite`.

When you specify `mod_rewrite` directives in a per-directory context, like with `.htaccess` or the `Directory` section of a server or virtual server configuration, the rewrite comes late in the Apache processing stage. To do its magic here, `mod_rewrite` has to perform an internal redirect every time that your URL is rewritten.

Since your rewrite could point you to a different directory, `mod_rewrite` assigns itself as the handler for this redirection so that it can go through whatever rules it may find at the new location you've sent the request to. Often, since you're only dealing with a single `.htaccess` file in your root, the rules in the "new" location happen to be the ones that caused the rewrite in the first place.

So, in your case, the following happens:

- Request made for `/css/A01EF`
- `mod_rewrite` starts the ruleset
- `^css/([0-9a-fA-F]{32})$ -> assets.php?hash=A01EF`
- `L` flag stops rewrite and forces internal redirect to `assets.php?hash=A01EF`
- `mod_rewrite` starts the ruleset over again
- `^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$` -> `index.php?url=assets.php&hash=A01EF` (you could use `QSA` here, by the way)
- `L` flag stops rewrite and forces internal redirect to `index.php?url=assets.php&hash=A01EF`

It's likely that this loop would continue, but `mod_rewrite` recognizes that you're redirecting to the same page and ignores your rewrite after this point.

This whole process happens to be why the two conditions...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

...are so common in `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite` rulesets, given that they provide an easy way to determine if the URL has already been rewritten to the intended real resource. You could use them, or you can exclude the `index.php` rewrite when the request has been rewritten to `assets.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```