# Redirect root of parked domain in one way, all other urls in another way, using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I recently got an alternate domain (parked) and would like it to behave like this:

- on a request for "alt-domain.com/" (root): serve "main-domain.com/fakeroot" without a redirect (200)
- on a request for "alt-domain.com/anyotherpage": serve "main-domain.com/anyotherpage" with a redirect (301)

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alt-domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ 
Rewriterule ^(.)$ /fakeroot.php  [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alt-domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Each rule works on its own, but when both are present the request for root also get a redirect. I tried inverting the order, tried skipping [S=1], tried [NS], but no luck. That's when I realized I'm not an htaccess expert, nor a regex expert.

Any help would be much appreciated.

D.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `L` flag probably [doesn't work like you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482106/rewrite-problem-last-not-being-respected/3482267#3482267), and when `mod_rewrite` re-examines your rules, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$` matches because the `%{REQUEST_URI}` is updated to `/fakeroot.php` after the initial rewrite.

There are a few different ways to fix this, but I believe this should work well enough, and it doesn't involve changing much:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alt-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ 
Rewriterule ^(.)$ /fakeroot.php  [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alt-domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(fakeroot\.php)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work, even when all looks fine when looking at it. I ended up redirecting all except the root with htaccess, and using the homepage code to serve different content when the alternate domain is detected.
Thanks for your help