# More Eyeballs on my Poor mod_rewrite Attempt Please

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, hotlinking

We're changing the way users embed images in their blogs, but I need to make sure previously embedded images are still displayed.

I'm trying to redirect legacy image embed links to either a static image or a single legacy image embed handling file. I'm using mod_rewrite, but it appears I fail. Amazingly, I've managed to cobble together a functional ruleset that prevents hotlinking.

I'm having some difficulty with redirecting legacy embeds to the single legacy handler though. This rule comes under the hotlink set `[L]`, so should only be evaluated if the embed request isn't a result of hotlinking.

Here is my attempt at redirecting all requests to any file like `gp[2]?.php[5]?\?p=(.*)`

```
    RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} gp[2]?\.php[5]?(.*)=(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule gp[2]?\.php[5]?(.*)=(.*)$ /legacy/gp.php5$1=$2 [L]
```

But it doesn't work, I just get my wonderful 404 page.

Some example requests:

```
http://ecpod.com/includes/gp.php5?p=cfcfbfbe5d9d63eab4a3e784bd30cfe016fcfcfbfbe5d9d6a19ebc57139d56bb
http://www.ecpod.com/includes/gp.php5?p=928e3888a526b462b684aea5609016f928e3888a585d0963ac4ebb335a522e09
http://www.ecpod.com/includes/gp2.php?p=cfcfbfbe5d9d63eab4a3e784bd30cfe016fcfcfbfbe5d9d6a19ebc57139d56bb
```

What I'm aiming for is to have any request that looks like one of those examples directed to:

```
http://ecpod.com/legacy/gp.php?p=HASH
```

Thank you for any help.

**Edit**:

Legacy urls *will* have `gp|gp2`, `php|php5` and a query string of n length. They may not necessarily be in the `includes` directory. It's messy and horrible, I know. Image embeds are handled differently now, this shall never happen again.

**Logs**:

```
RewriteRule ^/(includes/)?gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5 [NC,L]

192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:44:27 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b7d543aa390][rid#2b7d68ec65a8/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] add path info postfix: /site/http/web/includes -> /site/http/web/includes/gp.php
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:44:27 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b7d543aa390][rid#2b7d68ec65a8/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/includes/gp.php -> includes/gp.php
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:44:27 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b7d543aa390][rid#2b7d68ec65a8/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '^/(includes/)?gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'includes/gp.php'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:44:27 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b7d543aa390][rid#2b7d68ec65a8/initial] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] pass through /site/http/web/includes

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=[^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(includes/)?gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5?%2 [NC,L]

192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:43:53 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b8a2ad73400][rid#2b8a2b0ed438/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] add path info postfix: /site/http/web/includes -> /site/http/web/includes/gp.php
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:43:53 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b8a2ad73400][rid#2b8a2b0ed438/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/includes/gp.php -> includes/gp.php
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:43:53 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b8a2ad73400][rid#2b8a2b0ed438/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '^/(includes/)?gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'includes/gp.php'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:43:53 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b8a2ad73400][rid#2b8a2b0ed438/initial] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] pass through /site/http/web/includes


RewriteRule /gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5 [NC,L]

192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642705a8/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] add path info postfix: /site/http/web/includes -> /site/http/web/includes/gp.php
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642705a8/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/includes/gp.php -> includes/gp.php
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642705a8/initial] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'includes/gp.php'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642705a8/initial] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'includes/gp.php' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642705a8/initial] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642756c0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642756c0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642756c0/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642756c0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b1264277fa8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b1264277fa8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b1264277fa8/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b1264277fa8/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427a7e8/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427a7e8/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427a7e8/initial/redir#3] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427a7e8/initial/redir#3] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427cfe0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427cfe0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427cfe0/initial/redir#4] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427cfe0/initial/redir#4] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427f948/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427f948/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427f948/initial/redir#5] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b126427f948/initial/redir#5] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c3048/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c3048/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c3048/initial/redir#6] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c3048/initial/redir#6] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c5800/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c5800/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c5800/initial/redir#7] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c5800/initial/redir#7] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c81f0/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c81f0/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c81f0/initial/redir#8] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642c81f0/initial/redir#8] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642cad80/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642cad80/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642cad80/initial/redir#9] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642cad80/initial/redir#9] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642cd840/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /site/http/web/legacy/gp.php5 -> legacy/gp.php5
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642cd840/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /site/http/web/] applying pattern '/gp2?\.php5?$' to uri 'legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642cd840/initial/redir#10] (2) [perdir /site/http/web/] rewrite 'legacy/gp.php5' -> '/legacy/gp.php5'
192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:14:45:37 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b1256a153b0][rid#2b12642cd840/initial/redir#10] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] internal redirect with /legacy/gp.php5 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

**Outside `<Directory>`**:

```
http://www.ecpod-dev.dev/includes/gp.php?p=ff2287e8bb45572e38304afa184ba1a464016fff2287e8bb45572e0606111e7a

RewriteRule ^/(includes/)?gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5 [NC,L]

192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:23:46:54 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2ac33a5a83d0][rid#2ac34f0c4608/initial] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] pass through /site/http/web/includes

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=[^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(includes/)?gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5?%2 [NC,L]

192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:23:47:47 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2b02af320470][rid#2b02bcb7b688/initial] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] pass through /site/http/web/includes

RewriteRule /gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5 [NC,L]

192.168.1.4 - - [06/Sep/2010:23:48:45 +1200] [www.ecpod-dev.dev/sid#2aea076a73b0][rid#2aea14f025a8/initial] (1) [perdir /site/http/web/] pass through /site/http/web/includes
```

Comment: Just guessing that `ewriteRule` is a opy & aste error? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to the `RewriteRule` test pattern will not contain the query string, so testing for it will prevent the rule from ever matching and applying.

Taking that into account, we can rework the rule into something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(includes/)?gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5 [NC,L]
```

Assuming that the query string will already be in the format you want, we can just let `mod_rewrite` append it automatically by not specifying a replacement in our rewrite.

If you aren't sure that the query string will always be just `p=HASH`, and want to guarantee that it will be for the target script, we can extend the rule block to take that into account, looking for the `p` parameter in the query string and replacing the existing query string with just that piece:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=[^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(includes/)?gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5?%2 [NC,L]
```

Per [Roland Illig's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225757/roland-illig) comment, you could also do the following to be less restrictive on the directory the file is in:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/legacy/
# Input to RewriteRule in .htaccess never has a leading slash, so make sure
# we're at the beginning or there was a slash before the filename
RewriteRule (^|/)gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php5 [NC,L]
```

**Edit**: Changed rules to reflect how they would be defined in `httpd.conf` instead of `.htaccess`.
**Edit**: ...And then changed it back again.

Comment: I suggest `RewriteRule /gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php?%2 [NC,L]` instead. It's shorter, doesn't need a specific directory and makes sure that the `php5?` comes at the very end of the URI.

Comment: @Roland Illig - Whoops, I had forgotten the end anchor. I also removed the unnecessary character classes. If we just anchor at the end though, we need an additional `RewriteCond` to [prevent an internal redirect loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482106/rewrite-problem-last-not-being-respected/3482267#3482267) since the test pattern matches what we rewrite to. That might not be a bad idea depending on the scenario though, so I'll add that in as another option.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I tried them all, but this http://www.ecpod.com/includes/gp.php?p=eb95f287d3647971045ab284adce523016feb95f287d364797e035baabad68f8 still gives 404.

Comment: @Michael Robinson - When I click the link, I see an image that says "ECPod Share Your World", so did you get it to work just now?

Comment: Oops, I just see that I got it wrong. The documentation clearly says that *The Substitution of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the original URL-path that was matched by Pattern.* So you should try `RewriteRule (?:^|.*/)gp2?\.php5?$ /legacy/gp.php [NC,L]`. I don't know if that works in a `.htaccess` file though.

Comment: @Tim I think that is because you're clicking the link from SO, so you don't have the correct referral header. There is hotlinking protection on those urls that works ok... If you refresh that page a few times you'll see it not working

Comment: This is all happening in a `httpd.conf` file, not `.htaccess`

Comment: @Michael Robinson - Ah, I see, I do get the 404 now. So you're defining the rules in `httpd.conf`? (I had assumed `.htaccess` based on your question tags) I've updated the rules accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, I tried them all but still get the 404 page... If it's rewriting properly one should see a blank page, as `/legacy/gp.php5` echo's a blank string.

Comment: @Michael Robinson - I assume you noticed, but I had it rewriting to `gp.php` instead of `gp.php5`. I fixed the answer to reflect that change. As you have access to `httpd.conf`, can you make a [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) with `RewriteLogLevel` set to 9? Hopefully then we could figure out what's going on to mess this up.

Comment: Appended output to my question

Comment: @Michael Robinson - Thanks! Do you have these rules in a `<Directory>` section inside of `httpd.conf` or something? `mod_rewrite` is operating in a per-directory context, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Yeah I do, are they allowed in there?

Comment: @Michael Robinson - They're allowed, but it's better (if you have access to `httpd.conf` like you do) to define them directly in the server/virtual server configuration. If you'd rather not do that, I need to revert the rules a bit, because defining them in `<Directory>` is the same as defining them in `.htaccess`.

Comment: I've tried the rules inside / outside of `<Directory>`, still no joy :(

Comment: @Michael Robinson - The `RewriteLog` should look a bit different when they're outside of `<Directory>`, would you mind posting anything new?

Comment: @Michael Robinson - Hmm...This may sound like a stupid question, but did you make sure to put a `RewriteEngine On` with the rules you put outside of the `<Directory>`? It sounds like there's one still inside the `<Directory>`, but maybe not one outside it. My log shows (for rules outside) `(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /includes/gp2.php5` ... `(2) local path result: /legacy/gp.php5` (so it works fine on my server), but yours only seems to have the per-directory line still.

Comment: Yah just checked, it's on outside the directory

Comment: @Michael Robinson - That's...really odd. Alright. I've changed the rules back. Put these rules into the `<Directory>` section where you had them, then please post any changes to the `RewriteLog`, and hopefully we'll finally get something that works in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`RewriteRule ^\/includes\/gp\.php5?\?p=([a-f,0-9]{64})$ /legacy/gp.php?p=$1`

Comment: Hmm, I tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work.. legacy urls can be either `php` or `php5`, and the file may not be in the `includes` dir... Should have said that in the question sorry.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^\/(includes\/)?gp\.php5?\?p=([a-f,0-9]{64})$ /legacy/gp.php?p=$2`

That makes the includes/ dir optional and the question mark after the 5 in php5 makes that character optional.  Use the rewrite alone without and [] modifiers.  It should work (I have no place to really test it)