# Flash Video with HTML5 fallback using mediaelement.js

Tags: video, actionscript, mediaelement.js

Instead of flash fallback, I need construct my page so that I play Flash video with html5 video as a fallback
http://mediaelementjs.com/

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only case in which you would serve flash to a new browser, and HTML 5 as a 'fallback' is for iOS devices. So try sniffing for iOs devices like in this post:
[iPad/iPhone browser sniffer with mod_rewrite and redirection; "too many redirections"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131158/ipad-iphone-browser-sniffer-with-mod-rewrite-and-redirection-too-many-redirecti)

Or this one using javascript:
http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone

When you know you have a modern browser, but no flash support, then use the HTML5  tag.

Comment: That's not entirely true.  I've found that mp4 offers a higher quality than Ogg for example, and the fullscreen capabilities of Flash are better than html5 video.  I always use Flash first, then HTML5.  I'd be interested in the answer to the OP's question as well.