# Iphone detection php

Tags: php, iphone, redirect, detection

I have several Index.php files, such as (index.php, index2.php, index3.php etc.), I also have a database with different ID URL's. when some one enters a index file, the landing pages the see are dynamic and only the specified parameters in the database changes some of the parameters on display, lets say i enter domain.com/index.php?id=2 - this is for X city and the domain domain.com/index2.php?id=112 will display a page for Y city.

So far so Good..

now i am trying to insert a Iphone detection code, that will redirect users that are entering the urls from iphone to an iphone friendly design. so i created an i-index.php inserted the following code into the index.php page:

```
<?
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
{
  header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/mobile/i-index.php');
  exit();
}
?>
```

and now when i enter the url mydomain.com/index.php?id=1 from my iphone i am redirected to the i-index.php file but not to the specified ID (?id=1).

i hope my explanation is not to confusing. can anyone suggest a way for it to redirect to the specified ID (both original index and the mobile index are connected to the database correctly)

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any `?id=1` in your code

Comment: See this about how the PHP detected the iPhone. 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632400/iphone-detection-php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
{
  header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/mobile/i-index.php?id='.$_GET['id']);
  exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> so i created an i-index.php inserted

...

> header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/mobile/i-index.php');

So if an iphone requests i-index.php, that script sends a redirect to i-index.php

?

> not to the specified ID (?id=1).

Where does it say '?id=1' in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/mobile/i-index.php?id='.$_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Keep searching in the web

```
<?php

function isIphone($user_agent=NULL) {
    if(!isset($user_agent)) {
        $user_agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';
    }
    return (strpos($user_agent, 'iPhone') !== FALSE);
}

if(isIphone()) {
    header('Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/phone');
    exit();
}

// ...THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE

?>
```

and in javascript you say

```
var agent = navigator.userAgent;
var isIphone = ((agent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (agent.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) ;
if (isIphone) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/phone';
}
```

[Detect iPhone Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827466/detect-iphone-browser)

Answer (score 0):

This will add the whole query string to the `i-index.php`. So any querystring you receive will be passed to the i-Phone version also. This is good for future changes if you need to add some more parameter to `index.php` you don't have to change this code again.

```
<?

if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
{
  header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/mobile/i-index.php?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not doing this in PHP but [using RewriteEngine in a .htaccess file](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-syntax).
This might look something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/i-index.php
RewriteRule .* /mobile/i-index.php [R,QSA]
```

The `QSA` is taking care of the query string and adding the original parameters to the new url and therefore gives you more flexibility.

There is also a more sophisticated version available [in a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131158/ipad-iphone-browser-sniffer-with-mod-rewrite-and-redirection-too-many-redirect).