# .htaccess in root and subfolder, each to redirect to own index.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

*I apologise for a seemingly duplicate question, but none of the dozens I've looked at actually had the same problem.*

I have the following directory structure:

```
/.htaccess
/index.php
/subfolder/.htaccess
/subfolder/index.php
```

I'd like all requests for pages to be handled by `/index.php`, unless the request starts `/subfolder` in which case it should be handled by `/subfolder/index.php`

- e.g. `/abc` to be rewritten to `/index.php?u=abc`
- e.g. `/subfolder/def` to be rewritten to `/subfolder/index.php?u=def`

*I've been going round in circles over this, so any help will be massively appreciated.*

EDIT: forgot to mention the problem!
Requests within the subfolder are handled by the root `index.php`, not the subfolder one. (Except requests for `/subfolder`)

#### Current File contents

`/.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

`/subfolder/.htaccess`

```
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have your root .htaccess like this:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!admin/)(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ /admin/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

There is no need to have .htaccess in admin folder for this simple requirement.

Comment: @anubhava this does not work when WordPress is the main site and CodeIgniter is in `subfolder `, what could be the reason. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467868/codeigniter-app-in-wordpress-subdomain-sub-folder

Comment: Most of the `mod_rewrite` rules don't work with PHP frameworks with a front controller architecture like WP, Joomla, CI etc. Better to use framework provided APIs for rewriting stuff instead of `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 2):

This line of the root folder .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

is causing all the requests to non-existent filepaths to  be redirected to the root folder's `index.php`. That's the problem. 
One possible solution could be to substitute the above line with this couple of lines:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

By adding the `L` (last) flag and writing the rules in this order you'll get Apache to redirect correctly your requests, and eliminate the need for rewriting directives into `/subfolder/.htaccess` .

Comment: I tried similar at one point. Wouldn't that [L] make it a redirect?

Comment: @jezmck No, that is done by the [R] flag. [L] causes the rewriting to be stopped from further rules application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482106/rewrite-problem-last-not-being-respected/3482267#3482267 explains what I meant by that.