# Mod_rewrite swf file to another directory

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a client's site that used to have all .swf files in directories via product code eg. `g18/g18_flashfile.swf` but now i've moved them into `assets/flash/g18_flashfile.swf`

I have tried to mod_rewrite the request to the new location due to external sites hotlinking to the file. This just error 500s

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.swf$ assets/flash/$1/$2\.swf [L]
```

I also cannot just do a redirect anything as I am already using the following

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ product.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

Any help would be great as I am scratching my head on this one.

EDIT

Whats even stranger is when I do

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.swf$ assets/flash/$1/$2\.html [L]
```

It works (obviously it 404s because there isn't a .html file) but the rewrite works. Does anyone know if swf are some kind of term used in mod_rewrite?

Comment: What's even wierder is that when I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression

```
^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.swf$
```

matches both `g18/g18_flashfile.swf` and `assets/flash/g18_flashfile.swf`. Since the `L` flag [might not work as you expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482106/rewrite-problem-last-not-being-respected/3482267#3482267), this is a problem.

Just change the regular expression so that it doesn't match your rewritten path:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.swf$ assets/flash/$1/$2\.swf [L]
```